# Wave Analytics -- containerId/versionId of a dataset

Tags: einstein-analytics

How to get containerId/versionId of a dataset ? Previously we used to get this by turning on the SAQL mode, but after Summer 17 release it's only showing the dataset name, not the containerId/versionId names. Please let me know if we anyone has any idea how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

It is still shown in the logs:

- Open the Javascript console in the browser.
- Enable logs:

edge.log.enabled = true;
    edge.log.query = true

- Open the dataset
- Change it. For example, set a "Group by" parameter.

You will see the query in the Javascript console, which includes the identifiers you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Open workbench select the REST-api using the following route:

> /services/data/v37.0/wave/datasets/"your datasetId"

Select GET as method and the response will contain the version url along with other information. The click version url and the GET method you will return the version id.

Comment: how can I do this in apex?